# Phonegap, how to fire a function when Navbar Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cordova

I'm working on an app for learning purpose.

Theres a header, content and navbar with 2 buttons.

The body="onLoad()" function works really well when the app is starting, but when I click on another button at the navbar I would like to fire a function which is displaying the content for the page. But when I call a function in the new HTML file exactly the same way like on the index file (body="contentLoader()") it doesnt fire!

Heres the code from the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
</head>


<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

And now I would like to click on the "Listview"-Button at the navbar, which has a own HTML page, also with

```
<body onload="onListLoad()">
```

But my javascript function `function onListLoad() { alert("test"); }` is not fireing.

I can't figure out why. Isnt this the normal way?

Thanks in advance. Regards, john.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the  tag within your sub page is stripped out within PhoneGap.  Only the main index page will fire its onload method.

From what I gather, you're trying to fire some code as soon as one of your nav tabs is activated.   I'm not sure I can tell you the 'proper' way to do it, but here is what I do:

```
<div data-role="page" id="reports-browse">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$('#tab1').show(); $('#tab2').hide();" class="ui-btn-active">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$('#tab1').hide(); $('#tab2').show();">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="tab1">This is my first tab</div>
        <div id="tab2" style="display:none">This is my second tab.</div>
    </div>
    <script src="reports.browse.js"></script>
    <script>reports_browse.init();</script>
</div>
```

My init() function then does:

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function( prev_page ){
     // Populate the two tabs here.
});
```

Hope this helps.